# is it possible to can declare the string "My Text" in javascript and just refernce it in between <text> tags?

Tags: svg, tags

*So this is my code guys. so can someone please assist by showing me how to declare the text "My Text" as a ajavascript variable and just reference it on my html code using the keyword id*

```html
<svg>

  <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10"/>
  
   <text x="10" y="40">**My Text**</text>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the variable from the HTML, but you can use the JavaScript to reference and adjust the HTML.

Try something like this ...

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10"/>
  <text id="s_text" x="10" y="40">**My Text**</text>
</svg>
```

... (note the `id="s_text` on the text tag).  Then ...

```
document.getElementById("s_text").innerHTML = "Bob Fornal";
```

Reference jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/ds4evn8L/